# How to move header to bottom in stackNavigator in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using `react-navigation`. I want `createStackNavigator` style navigation, but I just want the header to be at the bottom of the screen instead of the top. It seems the only way to get a bottom navbar without making my own navigator is with `createBottomTabNavigator`.
I'm making a flow, with one screen following another until it ends.

The `headerStyle` prop doesn't take positioning properties like `bottom`, `top`, `left`.

Following some advice here, this is now what I have.

```
import BottomStackNavigationView from '../components/BottomStackNavigationView'

export default class MyScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'giraffe',
    headerTitle: 'monkey',
    headerBackTitle: 'c3po',
    header: (props) => <BottomStackNavigationView {...props} />,
  }

  render() {}
```

I log the props I get in my BottomStackNavigationView and it doesn't look like I am getting, for example, `headerTitle`, `title`, or `headerBackTitle`.

Is there a better way of doing this than making a custom navigator?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@Darpan Rangari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4736799/darpan-rangari) in the comments, `position: absolute` is not available in `headerStyle` so the below solution should work.

Try this:

```
export default class MyScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: (navigationOptions) => (<View style={{position:"absolute", bottom: 0, height: 80, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#dbdbdb"}}><Text>{navigationOptions.headerTitle}</Text></View>); //this is your custom header

  render() {}
}
```

Comment: position absolute is not supported on headerStyle.

Comment: Tried it, just doesn't render the header in this case.

Comment: @FilippoArgenti I didn't give a `height` and a `backgroundColor` to the custom view. Try giving that and see. (Edit: Made edits in the code, apply the edited version and see).

Comment: @DarpanRangari I couldn't find any reference to that. [See this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerstyle), there's no mention of any props being restricted. Maybe you checked the code?

Comment: I ran a code in my local, and i can see react in throwing a warning that 'position absolute is not supported on headerStyle'

Comment: So yes, after putting in a height this does allow me to put the header on the bottom, but it's just a plain `View`, it doesn't use any of the `navigationOption` props like `headerTitle`, etc.

Comment: @FilippoArgenti Try accessing the `navigationOptions` like I updated in the code above. The [documentation says](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#header) that `header` is a "React Element or a function that given `HeaderProps` returns a React Element, to display as a header. Setting to null hides header." I don't know what the `HeaderProps` are but they are accessible in the `header` function. So accessing the `headerTitle` should be pretty easy.

Comment: Looks interesting.. Is this missing a closing curly bracket on the navigationOptions?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a footer at the bottom of my stack navigator too. When `bottom: 0` didn't work, I found the height of my screen, and used:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { Dimensions, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const styles = {
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '100%',
  height: 130,
  top: Dimensions.get('window').height-130,
  backgroundColor: 'orange',
}

const A = props => (
  <Text style={{width: '50%', height: 200, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
    onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('B')} />
)

const EventCreationStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    A: {screen: A},
    B: {screen: A},
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: props => <View style={styles} />,
    },
  }
)

export default EventCreationStack
```